# Rest controller not registerring

Tags: spring-boot, rest, maven, security

I am building an app with JWT security but it keeps ignoring my rest controllers, and not registering the APIs:

Here is my pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>org.home</groupId>
    <artifactId>testapp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>testapp</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.25</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SECURITY -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JWT -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is my application.yml

```
...
server:
  url: https://localhost:8443
  port: 8443
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    key-store: classpath:keystore/my_keystore.p12
    key-store-password: mySuperPassword#
    key-store-type: pkcs12
    key-alias: mykey
```

Here is my main class :

```
package org.home.mysecurityapplication;
    
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"org.home.**"})
public class MySecureApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MySecureApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here is my web initializer :

```
package org.home.mysecurityapplication.configuration;

public class WebInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext sc) {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.setConfigLocations("org.home.**");
        rootContext.refresh();
        rootContext.setServletContext(sc);
        sc.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic apiSR = sc.addServlet("api-dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(rootContext));
        apiSR.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        apiSR.addMapping("/");
    }
}
```

Here i am evabling mvc :

```
package org.home.mysecurityapplication.configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"org.home.**"})
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

}
```

Here is my security configurer adapter:

```
package org.home.mysecurityapplication.security;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled=true, prePostEnabled=true)
public class MyWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final MyAuthenticationProvider myAuthenticationProvider;
    private final CredentialsFilter credentialsFilter;

    @Autowired
    public MyWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter(MyAuthenticationProvider myAuthenticationProvider, CredentialsFilter credentialsFilter) {
        this.myAuthenticationProvider = myAuthenticationProvider;
        this.credentialsFilter = credentialsFilter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/roles").permitAll() // everyone should access login-api
        ;

        // disable csrf
        http.csrf().disable();

        // app session is stateless
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http.addFilterBefore(credentialsFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        http.requiresChannel(channel -> channel.anyRequest().requiresSecure());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.eraseCredentials(false)
                .authenticationProvider(myAuthenticationProvider);
    }
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
package org.home.mysecurityapplication.security.controller;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="")
public class SecurityController {

    @Autowired
    private SecurityService securityServiceImpl;
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/roles", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces=MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public @ResponseBody
    String generateToken(@RequestBody CredentialsDTO credentials) throws MyRestPreconditionsException {
        logger.debug("User "+credentials.getUsername()+" logging in ...");
        String token = securityServiceImpl.generateTokenForUser(credentials);
        logger.debug("User "+credentials.getUsername()+" log in successfull.");
        return token;
    }
}
```

As you can see, rest controller **/roles** does not register :(

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.0)

2022-02-15 22:37:37.906  INFO 10720 --- [           main] l.h.myapp.MySecurityApplication   : Starting MySecurityApplication using Java 17.0.2 on HAL-9015 with PID 10720 (C:\Users\Lazaruss\IdeaProjects\greenhealth2\target\classes started by Lazaruss in C:\Users\Lazaruss\IdeaProjects\greenhealth2)
2022-02-15 22:37:37.909  INFO 10720 --- [           main] l.h.myapp.MySecurityApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2022-02-15 22:37:38.629  INFO 10720 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-02-15 22:37:38.712  INFO 10720 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 68 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-02-15 22:37:39.879  INFO 10720 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8443 (https)
2022-02-15 22:37:39.894  INFO 10720 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-02-15 22:37:39.894  INFO 10720 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.55]
2022-02-15 22:37:40.036  INFO 10720 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-02-15 22:37:40.036  INFO 10720 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2067 ms
2022-02-15 22:37:40.330  INFO 10720 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-02-15 22:37:40.406  INFO 10720 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.1.Final
2022-02-15 22:37:40.652  INFO 10720 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-02-15 22:37:41.061  INFO 10720 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2022-02-15 22:37:41.840  INFO 10720 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-02-15 22:37:41.851  INFO 10720 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-02-15 22:37:42.435  WARN 10720 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2022-02-15 22:37:42.957  INFO 10720 --- [           main] o.s.s.w.a.c.ChannelProcessingFilter      : Validated configuration attributes
2022-02-15 22:37:42.959  INFO 10720 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter@7af0693b, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@110318a7, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@265c0752, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@3c9cfcde, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@2e5c7cd5, lazaruss.home.myapp.security.CredentialsFilter@6dc2e473, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@7a75183d, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@6f695077, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@42ac309, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@799fc4c9, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@34fcc5e3, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@152dbf8e]
2022-02-15 22:37:43.681  INFO 10720 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8443 (https) with context path ''
2022-02-15 22:37:43.690  INFO 10720 --- [           main] l.h.myapp.MySecurityApplication   : Started MySecurityApplication in 6.437 seconds (JVM running for 7.137)
2022-02-15 22:37:49.009  INFO 10720 --- [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

Comment: Can you please include the package of each of the classes above? Thanks!

Comment: @João Dias done

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are having a problem with the scanned packages.

`@SpringBootApplication` encapsulates `@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, and `@ComponentScan` annotations with their default attributes. The default value for `@ComponentScan` means that all the sub packages on the package the `@ComponentScan` is used are scanned. That is why it is usually a good practice to include the main class in the base package of the project, so please make sure it is located there.

Having written this, try the following (drop `scanBasePackages` attribute and `@ComponentScan` annotation):

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class MySecureApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MySecureApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

}
```

Comment: It didn't work. (i also edited my question and added my dependencies in the pom)

Comment: Try removing `spring-web` dependency, it is already a transitive dependency of `spring-boot-starter-web`.

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: Try removing also `spring-context-support`, `spring-support` and `spring-data-jpa`. if this also does not work, consider cleaning the `pom.xml` by removing each dependency one by one, because most of those are already transitive dependencies of the `spring -boot-starter-*`.

Comment: I cleaned the pom of access dependencies, but that did not help ether. (new pom is updated into the question)

Comment: I am developing this in Intellij Community edition. I made the project skeleton by going here https://start.spring.io/ and downloading the zip file, and then importing it to intellij. Could it be something to do with that ? Or could it be something to do with my setup ? jdk or maven versions or something ?